# flash videoplayer not working properly

Tags: video, flash, browser, video-player

Flashs on websites are shown without any problem on both Firefox and Chrome. However, flash video players are not working properly; just background color and nothing at all. Interestingly youtube player is an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Mozilla website for plug-in. Install flash-aid or flash-video-replacer.

EDIT: flash-video-replacer is no longer offered

Answer (score 1):

It did not work for me with adobe-flashplugin package. Was resolved when I've install flashplugin-installer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do: (Im assuming you have flash 11 and firefox 14.0.1):

```
Download this file : http://www.ziddu.com/download/20225702/libflashplayer.zip.html

Create a folder "plugins" under "/home/YOUR-USER-NAME/.mozilla/firefox/"

Like this:  /home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins

Extract the zip and copy the downloaded "libflashplayer.so" to "/home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins"

Open nautilus as Admin. Go to "/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin". Delete the "libflashplayer.so" there.

Copy the extracted "libflashplayer.so" there.

Restart firefox.
```

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

sudo nautilus /etc/adobe/mms.cfg

And rename the file to something else(mms.cfg.bo)

Restart Firefox/Chrome and your videos should be working fine.